# Can't get to properties in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

Strangest problem. I have injected a "session" object into all controllers:

```
this.inject('controller','session','session:current');
```

I'm going to set the `accessToken` and `userId` properties but if I initialise these properties to `null` then they never get set. Initialisation is nothing more than:

```
App.Session = Ember.Object.extend({
    userId: null,
    accessToken: null
})
```

The result of the above initialisation, even though it's followed by the set() from below is this:

[image]

If I don't set them then the set() call sets these properties:

[image]

The set call in the init() method is:

```
this.set('accessToken', $.cookie('access_token'));
this.set('userId', $.cookie('userId'));
```

Feels like I've done this a 1000 times before without issue but something odd is happening here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---- UPDATE ----

Here's the `init()` function for additional context:

```
init: function() {
    this._super();
    console.log("Session started");
    this.set('accessToken', $.cookie('access_token'));
    this.set('userId', $.cookie('userId'));
    this.loginStatus();
},
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/NXnYG/4/  ... Am i missing any of your prob ??? Could you fiddle your problem ???

Comment: here's the code: http://codepen.io/kensnyder/pen/hxJot

Comment: Got you wrongly ???????

Answer (score 0):

If you overide the init method, it is possible to forget to call the super class init.

Try adding to your init method

```
init:function(){
     this._super();
     //your code
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks but I do have the call to _super() ... I'll update the question to include the full function.

Comment: Ok sorry, is an typical emberist error:-) I'd done a lot of times

Comment: Where is the init function(), inside ApplicationController or Inside App.Session

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you might have gone some misunderstanding with Em.O initialisation.

Whenever you create a instance of a class (in this case `App.Session` extending `Em.Object.extend`) , the properties in the class will be set in `__proto__` of the created instances. These properties will shared among the instances created from this class.

When you set the property using `Em.set`, the properties will be set as the `OwnProperties` of the instance rather than overriding the prototype properties and when you get a property using `Em.get`, the property are looked upon the OwnProperty first, if not found it will be looked upon the prototype chain till it reaches the root.

Ex Fiddles:

[Fiddle-1](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/zD356/1/)
[Fiddle-2](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/NXnYG/6/)

Sorry if i missed your point completely

Comment: I agree with you, that's my understanding too. I've posted an "answer" that I'm not too satisfied with but it may help you understand better what I'm struggling with. Furthermore, there are some embedded questions in my answer which you might have some insight on. :)

Comment: I cant find your ans !!

Comment: I was typing it up :)   It's there now.

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of trying to make my code work and so started from scratch, building up piece by piece. I think I've uncovered the heart of my problem and it's name collisions. To be fair, I'm still quite puzzled by this ...

Here's the registration and injection process:

```
Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
      console.log('App ready');
      this.register('session:current', App.Session, {singleton: true});
      this.inject('session:current','store','store:main');
      this.inject('controller','session','session:current');
  }
});
```

This works like a charm. First registering the Session as a singleton, then making sure that the store is available to the session object, and finally inserting a session property into each controller.

From there the Session object itself:

```
 App.Session = Ember.Object.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        console.log("Session started");
        this.set('accessToken', $.cookie('access_token'));
        this.set('currentUserID', $.cookie('userId'));
    },
    isLoggedIn: function() {
        return ( this.get('accessToken') && !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('currentUserID')) ) ? true : false;
    }.property('currentUserID','accessToken'),
    isLoggedOut: function() {
        return ! this.get('isLoggedIn');
    }.property('isLoggedIn'),

    userIdObserver: function() {
        console.log('Observing userId');
        $.cookie('currentUserID',this.get('currentUserID'));
    }.observes('currentUserID'),

    currentUser: function() {
        var self =  this;
        console.log("current user: " + this.get('currentUserID'));
        if (this.get('isLoggedIn')) {
            return  this.get('store')
            .find('user', this.get('currentUserID'))
            .then(function(profile){
                self.set('currentUser', profile);
            }, 
            function(error) {
                if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 400) {
                    // the access token appears to have expired
                    this.set('currentUserID', null);
                    this.set('accessToken', null);
                    self.transitionToRoute('login');
                } else {
                    // console.log("error getting user profile: " + error.status + ". " + error.responseJSON.error.message);            
                    console.log("error gettting user profile [" + this.get('userId') + "]");
                }
            });
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }.property('currentUserID')
});
```

This works -- assuming for a moment that a cookie for `currentUserID` and `accessToken` are set. Great. There's clearly some more code in Session to be built but why do I still feel a little uncomfortable? Two reasons:

1. Name collision. I had originally called `currentUserID` just `userId` but just doing a simple swap of names throws this solution into chaos. Well chaos may be a bit extreme but it definitely starts misbehaving. I kind of ran into this by accident.
2. Content array. I still can NOT initialise any of the properties like `currentUserID` as I normally would like to do. When I do that the property becomes a property of the App.Session (as I'd expect) but it also becomes "un-settable" from that point forward. Very odd. Well anyway, I can live with not initialising these variables but I'd prefer to understand why this does not work here but works everywhere else in Ember (at least in Controllers and Route objects).

Comment: Oh shit. I think the name conflict has been explained ... hadn't realised that the `userIdObserver` would conflict with `userId`.